# How to solve persistence unit on Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, jpa, eclipselink, persistence-unit

I had this web project setup on Glassfish, but I decided to move to Tomcat since I was having some problems.

But now my persistence class is throwing the following error

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named JetCarBd
```

I've tried placing the persistence.xml on different folders, but it haven't worked.

persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence     http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="JetCarBd" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
<provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
<class>br.com.jetcar.entity.Cliente</class>
<class>br.com.jetcar.entity.Endereco</class>
<class>br.com.jetcar.entity.Veiculo</class>
<class>br.com.jetcar.entity.Aluguel</class>
<class>br.com.jetcar.entity.Venda</class>
<class>br.com.jetcar.entity.Interesse</class>
<class>br.com.jetcar.entity.Funcionario</class>
<class>br.com.jetcar.entity.ItensAluguel</class>
<class>br.com.jetcar.entity.AcessorioAluguel</class>
<class>br.com.jetcar.entity.TestDrive</class>
<class>br.com.jetcar.entity.AcessorioVeiculo</class>
<class>br.com.jetcar.entity.Acessorio</class>
<class>br.com.jetcar.entity.Oficina</class>
<class>br.com.jetcar.entity.Manutencao</class>
<class>br.com.jetcar.entity.Reserva</class>
<exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
<properties>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"  value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/jetcar"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="postgres"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="postgres"/>
 </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

ConnectionUtil.java

```
package br.com.jetcar.connection;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

/**
 * @author Jorge Oliveira
 */
public class ConnectUtil {

private  final EntityManagerFactory emf;

public ConnectUtil(){
    emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("JetCarBd");
}

public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    return emf.createEntityManager();
}


}
```

My persistence.xml is located under src/META-INF

Answer (score 1):

You can check for couple of things here:

1. After you have deployed your application ensure that persistence.xml is available under

`WEB-INF/classes/META-IN`F folder

1. Your provider (eclipse jpa) jars are in the classpath, for Eclipse Env in build path, and also check if that is available in the deployed application.

Comment: I'm sorry, but where is located the folder that contains the deployed project by eclipse? In the glassfish it was right under the server folder.

Comment: In case you are deploying from eclipse then default folder is your <Your_Workspace>/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps. Alternatively you can double click on your sever and then check your deploy path(It will be visible in eclipse editor under Server Location

Comment: Alright, so the persistence.xml is under WEB-INF/classes/META-INF folder.I've the EclipseLink library as a user library on my project and because of that I get this warning on the Markers tab `Description Resource Path Location Type
Classpath entry org.eclipse.jdt.USER_LIBRARY/EclipseLink 2.3.2 - Indigo will not be exported or published. Runtime ClassNotFoundExceptions may result.   JetCar  P/JetCar Classpath Dependency Validator Message`. But I still get the library on the deploy.

Comment: Add this library in your WEB-INF/lib folder and redeploy, ensure all other dependencies are copied as well in WEB-INF/lib folder

Comment: After adding those libraries to the lib folder a bunch of errors showed up all of them referencing annotations like `Abr 23, 2012 3:56:09 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig checkHandlesTypes
WARNING: Unable to load class [org.apache.xml.resolver.Catalog] to check against the @HandlesTypes annotation of one or more ServletContentInitializers. 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.xml.resolver.Catalog`

Comment: Ok I solved the previous errors by removing com.sun.tools.xjc_2.2.0.jar from the libs, now I'm getting `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space`, I've tried adding more space in the catalina.bat, but it did no good.

`set JAVA_OPTS="-Xms1024m -Xmx10246m -XX:NewSize=256m -XX:MaxNewSize=356m -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m"`

Comment: When you are starting and stopping tomcat from eclipse default catalina.bat doesnt work you need to provide VM Parameters under run configuration (You should see Apache Tomcat listed in the left

Comment: Yeah, I just realized that, thank you for your help, everything is running as it should now, thanks again.